# Owl Carousel wont show up in index.php?

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I want the owl carousel plugin to show up on this wordpress/bootstrap theme but when I try to add it it doesn't show.

HTML

```
    <div class="row">
                   <div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel">
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/1170x300/42bdc2/FFFFFF"></div>
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/1170x400/42bdc2/FFFFFF"></div>
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/1170x500/42bdc2/FFFFFF"></div>
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/1170x200/42bdc2/FFFFFF"></div>
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/1170x500/42bdc2/FFFFFF"></div>
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/1170x250/42bdc2/FFFFFF"></div>
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/1170x350/42bdc2/FFFFFF"></div>
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/1170x300/42bdc2/FFFFFF"></div>
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/1170x100/42bdc2/FFFFFF"></div>
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/1170x500/42bdc2/FFFFFF"></div>
</div>

                </div>
```

CSS

```
#owl-demo .owl-item div{
  padding:5px;
}
#owl-demo .owl-item img{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

Is it something to do with using it within a wordpress theme?

Comment: Maybe you are not using the proper class selector. I don't see the `.owl-item` class in the `html` but well `.owl-carousel` and your css will not work.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be it either I'm beginning to think its a problem with wordpress or maybe the way I have things set up

Comment: its the js being called? owl carousel have to be initialized, maybe its not being initialized properly, try to do it with a custom js. $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel()

Comment: When you say it's not showing, are you not even seeing the placehold.it images at all?

Comment: Oh I totally forgot to inlcude the js in the quesiton but yes its correct and it doesn't show up at all and by not at all I mean the div, the container and the images dont show up

Comment: Maybe you should set the height not to auto, I had also once something like that. Try to set the height equal to the images height.

Comment: It worked but I don't know why there was nothing abstracting it from taking up more room. Mixing bootstrap with wordpress themes is weird XD